# React component doesn't update after updating state with redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-thunk

/keywordsActions

```
import { UPDATE_KEYWORDS } from "./actionTypes";
import queryString from "query-string";

const keywordsArrayFromUrl = () => {
  const query = queryString.parse(window.location.search);
  if (query.keywords) {
    const removeDuplicate = new Set(query.keywords.split(" "));
    return Array.from(removeDuplicate);
  }

  return [];
};

export function updateKeywords() {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_KEYWORDS,
      payload: await keywordsArrayFromUrl()
    });
  };
}
```

/keywordReducer

```
import { UPDATE_KEYWORDS } from "../actions/actionTypes";

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_KEYWORDS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

/SearchBar -- React Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
//Redux
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { updateKeywords } from "../store/actions/KeywordsAction";

class Searchbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      keywords : this.props.keywords
      keywordsString: this.props.keywords.join(" ")
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.updateKeywords();
    console.log(this.props)
    setTimeout(() => console.log(this.props), 10);
  }

  _handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ keywordsString: e.target.value });
  };

  _handleSearch = value => {
    this.setState({ keywordsString: value });
    this.props.history.push(`/search?keywords=${value}`);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Search
        className="Searchbar"
        placeholder="Cauta prin iBac..."
        value={this.state.keywordsString}
        onChange={this._handleChange}
        onSearch={this._handleSearch}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    keywords: state.keywords
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { updateKeywords }
)(withRouter(Searchbar));
```

I want to save the keywords from the Url to the store and then pass it to the Search bar state.

But i dont understand this :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.updateKeywords();
    console.log(this.props); // this.props.keywords is empty
    setTimeout(() => console.log(this.props), 10); // After 10 ms this.props.keywords is no empty 
  }
```

After 10 ms the props of Searchbar gets updated but the component doesn't render again.

Sorry for my question, I am really new to React / Redux. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you all!

Update :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.updateKeywords();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        keywordsString: this.props.keywords.join(" ")
      });
    }, 0);
  }
```

This code is also working... but this other is not working

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.updateKeywords();
      this.setState({
        keywordsString: this.props.keywords.join(" ")
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `componentDidMount` is only called once on mount. What you're looking for is either `componentShouldUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate` or the `render` function, all of which are called when your component receives the updated state from redux. You can read here for more information on what these functions do.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating

Comment: Nope, this doesn't fix it... but thank you for the answer!

Comment: did you try logging `this.props.keywords` in your render function? Did it change value?